# ShowCaseView Incorrectly rendering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I am using showCaseView legacy(which has the animation of the hand) in my android app. But, the gesture doesnt seem to start 'relative' to the view. Instead, it seems to be absolute to the screen. This is the following which i am using:

```
 final ShowcaseView sv;
      ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions co = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
      co.hideOnClickOutside = false;
    co.block=true;
      sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(R.id.pen, this," R.string.showcase_title"," R.string.showcase_message", co);
      View v=(View)findViewById(R.id.pen);
     sv.animateGesture(0, 0, 0, -500, false);
```

This is the top of my emulator, the animation STARTS from here: 
[image]
This shows a hand at the top left corner of the screen. (my guess is that the view's locations are being returned 0.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably going to be to use DisplayMetrics to place the hand, that's what I've done and it seems to work well.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics); 
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        float offsetEndY = height / 2 + 50;
        float offsetEndX = -width;
        float offsetStartY = height / 2 + 50;
        float offsetStartX = -width / 2;

        if (sv == null) {

            sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(width, 0, activity, "Menu", "Swipe to access more options", mOptions)
                    .setTextColors(Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK);
            sv.animateGesture(offsetStartX, offsetStartY, offsetEndX, offsetEndY);
```

Comment: this returns 0 inside my oncreate()

Comment: Did you try during onResume()? according to this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html onCreate is not the proper place to do this, you should try it later in the lifecycle. It is 0 because the view hasn't been drawn yet.

Comment: Does the circle show up for R.id.pen correctly? And what config options are you using? I'm using INSERT_TO_DECOR. Also have you tried on other devices or emulators? I've never used Genymotion so I can't really tell you how it handles measurements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I from logging showcase positions at different stages I found that proper position is strangely calculated some (very short) time after show() is called.
When I was calling

```
showcaseView.show();
showcaseView.animateGesture(0, 0, 0, -400);
```

this DIDN'T work.

Easy solution is show hand gesture with some delay (200 ms was enough in my case - tested on many devices):

```
showcaseView.show();
showcaseView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showcaseView.animateGesture(0, 0, 0, -400);
    }
}, 200);
```